# AWS Cognito Post-Confirmation Triggering Multiple Times

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am using AWS Cognito to create users and once the user status is confirmed, my requirement is to store the user's email and user's phone number in a table. For this, I am using the Post Confirmation Trigger. I am using AWS SAM to deploy the code onto AWS.

When the timeout is set to 3 seconds in the template.yaml, the trigger inserts the data in the table but throws an error:

```
PostConfirmation failed with error 2021-02-17T12:38:19.276Z f3d281dd-0dff-46a4-9154-3bb042a923c4 Task timed out after 3.00 seconds. (Service: AWSCognitoIdentityProviderService; Status Code: 400; Error Code: UserLambdaValidationException; Request ID: 242c6008-ef19-4015-b651-948620d8e04c; Proxy: null)
```

To avoid this error, I set the timeout in template.yaml to 5 seconds, which made the trigger to execute more than once even after user got confirmed, and I got this error:

```
User cannot be confirmed. Current status is CONFIRMED (Service: AWSCognitoIdentityProviderService; Status Code: 400; Error Code: NotAuthorizedException; Request ID: 50da31dc-5c03-4af3-adef-cafca16b1ad0; Proxy: null)
```

Please note that in both the cases, the user got confirmed and I got an entry in my table through the trigger. It is just that this error is misleading and I am suspecting that it is occurring due to timeout specified in the template.yaml.

If anyone has faced this issue with the post-confirmation trigger, please help as I want to avoid the error and understand the root cause.

Contents of template.yaml:

[template.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXDZf.png)

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  SAM Template
  
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 5
    Runtime: nodejs12.x

Parameters:
  cognitoUserPoolArn:
    Type: String
  userIamRool:
    Type: String
  StageName:
    Type: String
    Default: dev

Resources:
  AWSApiGateway:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      Name: xxxxxxx
      StageName: !Ref StageName
      Cors: "'*'"
      Auth:
        DefaultAuthorizer: MyCognitoAuthorizer
        Authorizers:
          MyCognitoAuthorizer:
            UserPoolArn: !Ref cognitoUserPoolArn
      GatewayResponses:
        UNAUTHORIZED:
          StatusCode: 401
          ResponseParameters:
            Headers:
              Access-Control-Expose-Headers: "'WWW-Authenticate'"
              Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"

  postConfirmationCognitoTrigger:  
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: build/
      Handler: postConfirmationCognitoTrigger.postConfirmationDentistTrigger
      Role: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxx:role/lambda-xxxxxxxx-executionrole
  
  GetPatientOnboardingQuestionnaireFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: build/
      Handler: getPatientOnboardingQuestions.lambdaHandler
      Role: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxx:role/lambda-xxxxxxxxxx-executionrole
      Events:
        HelloWorld:
          Type: Api 
          Properties:
            RestApiId: !Ref AWSApiGateway
            Path: /dev/api/v1/patient/getPatientOnboardingQuestions
            Method: GET
            Auth:
              Authorizer: 'MyCognitoAuthorizer'
```

Comment: If you can post the contents of template.yaml, it would help community members help you better.

Comment: @ofnowhere, I have now added the link for the image of Template.yaml as adding the code directly removed the indentation and made it difficult to understand. Thank You.

Comment: Are you aware of code formatting using Ctrl + k, it should help you format your code better.
Also, the content in the image is not easy to read, please add the relevant sections of the code.
I don't have the answer here, but the changes will help anyone who has the answer understand the question,

Comment: @ofnowhere, thanks for the letting me know about Ctrl+k, I have added the code after formatting through that. Hope it helps someone.